# How to Stop Bootstrap 3 Carousel Cycling at End of Slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/YqEx8XyUi6) and let me know how I can disable controls when the slider catches the lat item or the left control at beginning. I already tried this code

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel('pause')
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

  if($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
    $this.children('.left.carousel-control').hide();
  } else if($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
    $this.children('.right.carousel-control').hide();
  } else {
    $this.children('.carousel-control').show();
  }
})
```

but this is not functioning properly. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had 4 slides, and only 3 indicators, which probably wasnt helping with the confusion. Also good pickup by @Schmalzy on the `data-target`s on on the indicators.

I would suggest hooking into the `slid.bs.carousel` event rather than `slide`, as this will allow you to know which slide you're NOW on, as apposed to what you've just come FROM.

Due to the way bootstrap uses data attributes to know what indicator links to what slide, we can use these indexes to know what slide we are on when coupled with the `slid` event.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
$('#myCarousel').find('.carousel-control.left').hide(); // hide initial left control
var slideCount = $('#myCarousel').find('.carousel-indicators li').length; // get number of slides
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  var index = $(this).find('.carousel-indicators .active').data('slide-to'); // get the index of the slide we are NOW on
  if(index == 0){ // is first slide
    $(this).find('.carousel-control.right').show(); // add this in here in case only 2 slides
    $(this).find('.carousel-control.left').hide();
  }else if(index == slideCount - 1){ // is last slide
    $(this).find('.carousel-control.left').show(); // add this in here in case only 2 slides
    $(this).find('.carousel-control.right').hide();
  }else{ // is not first or last slide
    $(this).find('.carousel-control').show();
  }
})
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Ls7V4Fuh3H)**

PS. A lot can be said for storing these frequent `.find` calls as variables at the start to help optimise. ie:

```
var $myCarousel = $('#myCarousel');
var $myCarouselControls = $myCarousel.find('.carousel-control');
var $myCarouselControlsLeft = $myCarouselControls.filter('.left');
var $myCarouselControlsRight = $myCarouselControls.filter('.right');
var $myCarouselIndicators = $myCarousel.find('.carousel-indicators li');
$myCarousel.carousel('pause');
$myCarouselControlsLeft.hide();
var slideCount = $myCarouselIndicators.length;
$myCarousel.on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  var index = $myCarouselIndicators.filter('.active').data('slide-to');
  if(index == 0){ // is first slide
    $myCarouselControlsRight.show();
    $myCarouselControlsLeft.hide();
  }else if(index == slideCount - 1){ // is last slide
    $myCarouselControlsLeft.show();
    $myCarouselControlsRight.hide();
  }else{ // is not first or last slide
    $myCarouselControls.show();
  }
})
```

**[Optimised Demo](http://www.bootply.com/tw9pbXotNN)**

Comment: `data-target`s on the indicators are incorrect as well.